# How do you catch a cat on a tree?

Tags: graph-theory, game-theory

Suppose we have a finite (not directed) connected graph $ G $ with no loops (self-edges). There's a cat on one of the vertices of this graph but we don't know which.

We play the following game: at every turn, we can check one of the vertices to see if the cat is there or not. If the cat is there, we win. If the cat is not there, the cat gets a move in which it can move to any neighbor of the vertex it's currently at, and it *must* use this move. This is important: the cat can't sit in its current position, it has to move from it when its turn comes. Then we go on to the next turn in which we make a move and the cat makes a move, then to the next turn, etc. until we either catch the cat or fail to do so forever.

For which finite graphs $ G $ do we have a strategy that's guaranteed to win?

Some preliminary observations: what we're doing is defining a *directed* graph structure on the power set $ \mathbb P(V) $ of the vertices $ V $ of $ G $ and asking if we can get to the empty set from the set $ V $. For small graphs it's possible to exhaustively search this directed graph using depth-first search and determine whether there is a solution or not.

Furthermore, this picture also makes it clear that $ G $ must actually be a tree if we have a strategy that's guaranteed to catch the cat. This is because if there is a cycle in $ G $ which is initially included in a set, then after we make our observation we can exclude at most one vertex from this cycle, and since every vertex in the cycle has at least two neighbors when the cat makes its move it will still be possible for it to be anywhere along the cycle.

Here are some simple cases: we always have a winning strategy for the [path graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_graph) $ P_n $. If the vertices are $ 1 $ through $ n $, then we simply observe $ 2, 3, \ldots, n-1, n-1, n-2, \ldots, 3, 2 $ in order and we're guaranteed to catch the cat no matter what it does. If you don't see how this works, it's worth working it out explicitly.

Here is a tree for which we have no strategy that always wins:

[image]

I don't have a proof of this fact; it's verified by depth-first search as I mentioned earlier (though a proof for this specific case shouldn't be hard to find). However, some close cousins of this tree do have winning strategies, such as this one:

[image]

The optimal (in the sense of minimizing the number of moves in the worst case) solution for this graph takes at most fourteen moves to catch the cat. You can try to see if you can find it.

As I've said, I'm interested in any nontrivial results about trees of this type, so even if you don't have a full classification you can post whatever partial results you're able to prove.

**Note:** If anyone has confusions about the problem, [this Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11wmDReIhC_ZEzZ6ZqGpuNiBUgVVi2HmD?usp=sharing) contains an implementation of a verifier for whether there is an always-winning strategy for any given graph or not.

Comment: Clarification:  Moves are *alternating*, right?  And I presume if the cat is forced onto "my" vertex, then I win.  (If correct, you might want to update your posting.)

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Yes, moves are alternating between you and the cat. If you observe a vertex when the cat is there, then you win.

Comment: I've been told that this is a variant of the [pursuit-evasion problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pursuit%E2%80%93evasion#Variants) but Wikipedia has nothing to say about this specific variant of the problem so I don't know if this classification helps any.

Comment: It may speed up your depth-first search to use a bipartition $V = A \cup B$ of the tree. The cat will always alternate between the two sides; so draw a directed graph with vertex set $\mathbb P(A) \cup \mathbb P(B)$, and find a path from $A$ to $\emptyset$. (Then a path from $B$ to $\emptyset$ also exists, since there is an edge from $B$ to $A$; this means we catch the cat assuming it started on side $A$, and then if that didn't work catch the cat assuming it started on side $B$. That's how the $P_n$ strategy works, in particular.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov Yeah, I'm aware of this, but it's not a big speed gain so I didn't bother to implement it. Nice catch, though: it's possible the bipartition is useful not just for speeding up the search, but also for saying something about the graphs for which there is a winning strategy.

Comment: Something is wrong with your code. The graph $G_1 = {0: [1, 3, 5, 7], 1: [0, 2], 2: [1], 3: [0, 4], 4: [3], 5: [0, 6], 6: [5], 7: [0, 8], 8: [7, 9], 9: [8]}$ gives false but the graph $G_2 = {0: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9], 1: [0, 2], 2: [1], 3: [0, 4], 4: [3], 5: [0, 6], 6: [5], 7: [0, 8], 8: [7], 9: [0, 10], 10: [9, 11], 11: [10]}$ gives true, even though $G_1$ is a subset of $G_2$, i.e., ignore nodes $5,6$ in $G_2$ is the same as $G_1$.

Comment: @AsAnExerciseProve There was some bug with the initialization of the set of visited vertices in the depth-first search which led to wrong results if you ran the code consecutively on different graphs. It's fixed now: both of your graphs have solutions, one with 14 maximum moves and the other with 20. Thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Comment: clarification: cat's moves and player's move don't occur at the same time right? there's the player's move and if the cat is found game is over, otherwise cat to move.

Comment: Oh my gosh!  That's my cat on the tree; I recognize him because he's all black; if he turns his head, I'll confirm, given the color of his eyes!!  ;D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimal tree (by number of nodes) where you cannot catch the cat is this 10-node graph:

```
o
 \
  o
   \
    o
     \
      o - o - o - o
     /
    o
   /
  o
 /
o
```

Call this tree $Y$. I claim that if $T$ is any tree not containing $Y$, then you can catch the cat.  Here is a sketch of the argument:

If $T$ does not contain $Y$, then $T$ consists of a long path (the "spine") with some number of paths of length at most 2 (the "legs") coming out of each internal vertex (i.e. not an endpoint) of the spine. Some of the legs from an internal spine vertex may share another common leg-internal vertex, as in the second picture in the original post (see the central spine vertex).

To catch the cat, start with the first internal vertex of the spine. At each internal vertex $v$, if there are any legs of length 2 coming out of $v$, then for each such leg, step onto the leg's internal vertex and then immediately back to $v$. (Shared leg-internal vertices need only be visited once.) Then move to the next vertex of the spine. Repeat this until you get to the last internal spine vertex and handle all its legs of length 2. For the last leg of the last internal spine vertex $v$, you do not need to go back to $v$ after walking onto the leg. At this point, we have traversed all non-leaf vertices at least once, and the cat is restricted to one of the bipartitions of the tree. Now traverse the same vertices again, but in reverse order (again after traversing the last leg you don't need to go back). This will catch the cat.

For example:

```
A------B-------C-------D--------E---------F
      / \                       |
     G   H                      I
    /     \                     |
   J       K                    L
```

The winning sequence of guesses described above is
B, G, B, H, B, C, D, E, I (at this point we've traversed all the non-leaf vertices, now we do the same sequence in reverse, omitting the final B) I, E, D, C, B, H, B, G.

Comment: I haven't checked the details yet, but by [Robertson-Seymour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robertson%E2%80%93Seymour_theorem) we should expect this type of classification to work. +1 for the idea, I'll accept it when I have the time to go through it.